# How do I swap icons on buttons arranged in GridLayout using Drag and Drop?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, mouseevent

I'm trying to create a jigsaw puzzle of sorts, where I have loaded an image onto a 5x5 grid, cropped the image and assigned each cropped part as an icon to 25 buttons arranged in the same pattern. I want to be able to drag my mouse pointer from a button to another and swap the icons on those 2 buttons.

I've tried using multiple MouseListener methods and MouseMotionListener methods, but nothing has worked so far.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.CropImageFilter;
import java.awt.image.FilteredImageSource;
import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.*;
//import java.awt.image.*;
public class ImageMove {
    JFrame jf;
    JButton[][] grid;
    JLabel test;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ImageMove ob = new ImageMove();
        ob.start();
    }
    public void start() {
        jf = new JFrame();
        JPanel gridPanel = new JPanel();
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);      
        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("download.jpg");
        Image temp1= img.getImage();
        img=new ImageIcon(temp1.getScaledInstance(500, 500, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
        Image img1 = img.getImage();

        gridPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout (5,5));
        grid = new JButton[5][5];
        for(int y=0;y<5;y++) {
            for(int x=0; x<5; x++) {
                Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(new FilteredImageSource(img1.getSource(), new CropImageFilter(x * 500 / 5, y * 500 / 5, 100, 100)));
                ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
                JButton temp = new JButton(icon);
                temp.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("icon"));
                temp.addMouseMotionListener(new DragMouseAdapter());
                grid[x][y]=temp;                
                gridPanel.add(grid[x][y]);
            }
        }
        test= new JLabel();
        jf.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, test);
        jf.add(gridPanel);
        jf.pack();
        jf.setSize(500, 500);
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }
    class DragMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter{
        private int x, y;
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            final int x0=MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
            final int y0=MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;
            x=x0;
            y=y0;
            JButton c = (JButton) e.getSource();
            TransferHandler handler = c.getTransferHandler();
            handler.exportAsDrag(c, e, TransferHandler.COPY);

            }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            JButton c = (JButton) e.getSource();
            Icon icon = c.getIcon();
            grid[((int)(x/100))][((int)(y/100))].setIcon(icon);

        }

    }


}
```

Currently, the program copies the icon from the first button to the second button, i.e. it replaces the second button's icon with the first, but the first button remains the same. I expect to swap those two icons entirely. The MouseDragged method towards the end is performing the described behavior, but the MouseReleased doesn't seem to do anything at all.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy. You simply need to save somewhere the drag source button, and on drop replace its icon with the old icon of drop target button.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.CropImageFilter;
import java.awt.image.FilteredImageSource;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.TransferHandler;

//import java.awt.image.*;
public class ImageMove {
    JFrame jf;

    JButton[][] grid;

    JLabel test;

    JButton dragSource; // here we save drag source component

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ImageMove ob = new ImageMove();
        ob.start();
    }

    public void start() {
        jf = new JFrame();
        JPanel gridPanel = new JPanel();
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("download.jpg");
        Image temp1 = img.getImage();
        img = new ImageIcon(temp1.getScaledInstance(500, 500, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
        Image img1 = img.getImage();

        gridPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 5));
        grid = new JButton[5][5];
        for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
                Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
                        .createImage(new FilteredImageSource(img1.getSource(), new CropImageFilter(x * 500 / 5, y * 500 / 5, 100, 100)));
                ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
                JButton temp = new JButton(icon);
                // use own extension of TransferHandler
                temp.setTransferHandler(new MyTransferHandler("icon"));
                // start drag on mouse pressed event.
                temp.addMouseListener(new DragMouseAdapter());
                grid[x][y] = temp;
                gridPanel.add(grid[x][y]);
            }
        }
        test = new JLabel();
        jf.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, test);
        jf.add(gridPanel);
        jf.pack();
        jf.setSize(500, 500);
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }

    class DragMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            JButton c = (JButton) e.getSource();
            dragSource = c;
            TransferHandler handler = c.getTransferHandler();
            handler.exportAsDrag(c, e, TransferHandler.COPY);
        }

    }

    private class MyTransferHandler extends TransferHandler {
        public MyTransferHandler(String property) {
            super(property);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean importData(JComponent comp, Transferable t) {
            Icon targetIcon = ((JButton) comp).getIcon();
            boolean result = super.importData(comp, t);
            if (dragSource != null) {
                dragSource.setIcon(targetIcon);
                dragSource = null;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

}
```